# Related to dot product and vectors

Tags: vectors

For any vector $r$, prove that 
$$r = (r.i)i + (r.j)j + (r.k)k$$
I cannot satisfied myself with the solution in picture-https://photos.app.goo.gl/hjdqt93dSEq69cSX8
Since,
$$(r.i)i=r(i.i)=r|i|²=r$$
Similarly the other two terms gives $r$.
So, $$(r.i)i + (r.j)j + (r.k)k=3r$$
This is not equal to $r$.
So what is wrong in this solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I did everything: made the vectors bold,intended the equations in centre, uploaded the source image.But after uploading my question it looked like this.what should I do?

Comment: @Kartikey I don't know about your picture because my internet is bad. But I centered the equation for you. If you want to type mathematics correctly on this site, you can follow the following "MathJax" tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference If you want to make the vectors bold, you can try the following code `$\mathbf v$` to get  $\mathbf v$. Also compare with `$\vec v$` $\vec v$

Comment: @Kartikey It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the step

$$ (r\cdot i)i = r(i\cdot i)$$
This just isn't correct. For instance, suppose $r=j$. Then $j\cdot i = 0$, 
$$0= (j\cdot i)i \overset{\Huge!?}=j(i\cdot i) = j|i|^2 = j$$

The dot product doesn't work like this. Remember that $r\cdot i$ is a number. Any number $s$ times the vector $i$ gives $si$, a vector pointing in the direction $i$. On the other hand, $(i\cdot i)r$ is some other number $l$ times $r$, resulting in $lr$, a vector pointing in the direction of $r$. The numbers $r\cdot i,r\cdot j, r\cdot k$ are just the components.

Example- if $r = \begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$,
then $$r\cdot i=3,r\cdot j=1, r\cdot k=2$$